# ODE $y'=ay+b/y$; no idea

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to solve
$$y'(t)=ay(t)+\frac{b}{y(t)}, \quad a,b\in\mathbb{R}$$
and have literally no clue how to begin. Additionaly the endpoint value is given by a transversalitiy condition like $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-rt}x(t)y(t)=0$ where $$x'(t)=f(x,y)$$ and $x(0)=x_0$ given. 
The paper gives the solution as 
$$y(t)=-\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$$ 
which is the fixed point, but no idea why this must the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by $y(t)$, you get:

$$y(t)y'(t)=ay^2(t)+b$$

But it's equal:

$$\frac{1}{2}(y^2(t))'=ay^2(t)+b$$

Put $z(t)=y^2(t)$:

$$\frac{z'(t)}{2}=az(t)+b$$

Now it's a linear ODE.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ay+\frac by=\frac{ay^2+b}{y}\implies \frac{ydy}{ay^2+b}=dt\implies \frac1{2a}\ln|ay^2+b|=t+c$$

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply your equation by $y(t)$ you have: $$y(t)y'(t) = a(y(t))^2 + b$$
Recall that $\frac12 \frac{d}{dt} y^2 = y'(t)y(t)$. Using the substitution $z(t) = (y(t))^2$ we have $z'(t) = 2a z(t) + 2b$. Which leads to $$z'(t) - 2a z(t) = 2b$$ Multiply by $e^{-2at}$ to find: $$e^{-2at} b = e^{-2at} z'(t) - 2a e^{-2at} z(t) = (e^{-2at}z(t))'$$ Integrating both sides leads to $$e^{-2at} \frac{-b}{a} + \frac{b}{a} = e^{-2at}z(t) - z(0)$$
Solving for $z(t)$:

$$z(t) = e^{2at}z(0) + e^{2at}\frac{b}{a} - \frac{b}{a}$$

Finally $$y(t) = \pm \sqrt{ e^{2at}(y(0))^2 + (e^{2at}-1)\frac{b}{a}}.$$